# Vector store created using existing graph for multiple nodes/labels

Tags: neo4j, openai-api, langchain, large-language-model

Am trying to create vector stores on top of my existing KG using from_existing_graph, (followed tomaz  and Saurav Joshi neo4j blog posts) - this method is allowing me to create embedding/vector index only for single label due to which am unable to get desired results while asking NLQ (I am assuming though).

below code is able to answer, the age and location of Oliver but not what he directed,
i believe this is due to from_existing_graph has only to pass single label and its corresponding properties as option for generating embeddings and vector index
Any ideas, how to achieve this?

```
import os
import re
from langchain.vectorstores.neo4j_vector import Neo4jVector
# from langchain.document_loaders import WikipediaLoader
from langchain_openai import OpenAIEmbeddings
# from langchain.text_splitter import CharacterTextSplitter, RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter
from langchain.graphs import Neo4jGraph
import openai
# from transformers import AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM, AutoTokenizer

os.environ["OPENAI_API_KEY"] = "sk-xx"
url = "neo4j+s://xxxx.databases.neo4j.io"
username = "neo4j"
password = "mypassword"
existing_graph = Neo4jVector.from_existing_graph(
    embedding=OpenAIEmbeddings(),
    url=url,
    username=username,
    password=password,
    index_name="person",
    node_label="Person",
    text_node_properties=["name", "age", "location"],
    embedding_node_property="embedding",
)

from langchain.chat_models import ChatOpenAI
from langchain.chains import GraphCypherQAChain
from langchain.graphs import Neo4jGraph

graph = Neo4jGraph(
    url=url, username=username, password=password
)

chain = GraphCypherQAChain.from_llm(
    ChatOpenAI(temperature=0), graph=graph, verbose=True
)

query = "Where does Oliver Stone live?"
#query = "Name some films directed by Oliver Stone?" 

graph_result = chain.invoke(query)

vector_results = existing_graph.similarity_search(query, k=1)
for i, res in enumerate(vector_results):
    print(res.page_content)
    if i != len(vector_results)-1:
        print()
vector_result = vector_results[0].page_content

# Construct prompt for OpenAI
final_prompt = f"""You are a helpful question-answering agent. Your task is to analyze
and synthesize information from two sources: the top result from a similarity search
(unstructured information) and relevant data from a graph database (structured information).
Given the user's query: {query}, provide a meaningful and efficient answer based
on the insights derived from the following data:

Unstructured information: {vector_result}.
Structured information: {graph_result} """


from openai import OpenAI
client = OpenAI(
    # This is the default and can be omitted
    api_key=os.environ.get("OPENAI_API_KEY"),
)

chat_completion = client.chat.completions.create(messages=[{"role": "user","content": final_prompt,  }],model="gpt-3.5-turbo",)

answer = chat_completion.choices[0].message.content.strip()
print(answer)
```

Any help would be highly appreicated?

here is my schema:
Node properties are the following:

```
Person {name: STRING, embedding: LIST, age: INTEGER, location: STRING},Actor {name: STRING, embedding: LIST},Movie {title: STRING},Director {name: STRING, embedding: LIST, age: INTEGER, location: STRING}
Relationship properties are the following:
ACTED_IN {role: STRING}
The relationships are the following:
(:Person)-[:ACTED_IN]->(:Movie),(:Person)-[:DIRECTED]->(:Movie),(:Actor)-[:ACTED_IN]->(:Movie),(:Director)-[:DIRECTED]->(:Movie)
```

Cypher used to create:

```
CREATE (charlie:Person:Actor {name: 'Charlie Sheen'})-[:ACTED_IN {role: 'Bud Fox'}]->(wallStreet:Movie {title: 'Wall Street'})<-[:DIRECTED]-(oliver:Person:Director {name: 'Oliver Stone'});
MATCH (n:Person {name: 'Oliver Stone'}) SET n.age = 30, n.location = "New York" RETURN n
```

Comment: You need to give a good example to the LLM to generate a specific response.  What is your KG look like?  What is the result you are getting? What is the "Expected" result that you want?

Comment: @jose_bacoy , I have added my schema in my question above, 
am getting result as expected if i am asking a prompt like, "Where does Oliver Stone live?" this can be because i have created vector index on top of that and am consuming that as vector store using from_existing_graph where i have fetched details of Person label (name, age, location).
my problem is when i am trying to ask a "Name some films directed by Oliver Stone?", it is not able to answer this since it my vector store doesnt have this info, so , my question is how to feed this to my vector store so it can understand and answer

Comment: I see that movie is not part of the embedding, that is why the llm cannot figure out where to find the answer.  I see this article about supplementing the data with a relationship of the director (Oliver) to the movie (Wall Street).  We will use a retrieval query.  Read along this python notebook and check the bottom: https://github.com/tomasonjo/blogs/blob/master/llm/neo4jvector_langchain_deepdive.ipynb

Comment: I added my answer below. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the relationship :DIRECTED into the index person_index since the movie he directed is not part of the embedding. Once you have the query to add the movies he directed, you will then add it on the resulting node metadata (see retrieval_query).  Then on your vector result, you will add the information about the movie tile (as metadata movie[0]["title"]).

You may need to collect all movie titles if there are more than one movie titles in the graph. I'm sure you can figure it out.

Reference: https://github.com/tomasonjo/blogs/blob/master/llm/neo4jvector_langchain_deepdive.ipynb

```
import os
from langchain.vectorstores.neo4j_vector import Neo4jVector
from langchain_openai import OpenAIEmbeddings
import openai

os.environ["OPENAI_API_KEY"] = "sk-<key>"
url = "bolt://localhost:7687"
username = "neo4j"
password = "awesome_password"

retrieval_query = """
       MATCH (node)-[:DIRECTED]->(m:Movie)
       WITH node, score, collect(m) as movies
       RETURN node.name as text, score, node{.*, embedding: Null, movies: movies} as metadata
       """

existing_index_return = Neo4jVector.from_existing_index(
    embedding=OpenAIEmbeddings(),
    url=url,
    username=username,
    password=password,
    database="neo4j",
    index_name="person_index",
    text_node_property="name",
    retrieval_query=retrieval_query,
)

from langchain_openai import ChatOpenAI
from langchain.chains import GraphCypherQAChain
from langchain_community.graphs import Neo4jGraph

graph = Neo4jGraph(
    url=url, username=username, password=password
)

chain = GraphCypherQAChain.from_llm(
    ChatOpenAI(temperature=0), graph=graph, verbose=True
)

#query = "Where does Oliver Stone live?"
query = "Name some films directed by Oliver Stone?" 

graph_result = chain.invoke(query)

vector_results = existing_index_return.similarity_search(query, k=1)
vector_result = vector_results[0].page_content + " lives in " + vector_results[0].metadata["location"] + " and he directed the movie " + vector_results[0].metadata["movies"][0]["title"]

# Construct prompt for OpenAI
final_prompt = f"""You are a helpful question-answering agent. Your task is to analyze
and synthesize information from two sources: the top result from a similarity search
(unstructured information) and relevant data from a graph database (structured information).
Given the user's query: {query}, provide a meaningful and efficient answer based
on the insights derived from the following data:

Unstructured information: {vector_result}.
Structured information: {graph_result} """


from openai import OpenAI
client = OpenAI(
    # This is the default and can be omitted
    api_key=os.environ.get("OPENAI_API_KEY"),
)

chat_completion = client.chat.completions.create(messages=[{"role": "user","content": final_prompt,  }],model="gpt-3.5-turbo",)

answer = chat_completion.choices[0].message.content.strip()
print(answer)
```

Sample output:

```
> Entering new GraphCypherQAChain chain...
Generated Cypher:
MATCH (d:Director {name: "Oliver Stone"})-[:DIRECTED]->(m:Movie)
RETURN m.title
Full Context:
[{'m.title': 'Wall Street'}]

> Finished chain.
Based on the unstructured information retrieved from the top result of the search, Oliver Stone directed the film "Wall Street." 

In addition to "Wall Street," some other films directed by Oliver Stone include "Platoon," "JFK," "Born on the Fourth of July," "Natural Born Killers," and "Snowden."
```

Comment: yw, Santhosh. hope it works for you and accept my answer. Thanks!